# Outputting a string pointer array

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out exactly what I am doing wrong here, and haven't found any posts with the same issue.  I am using a dynamic array of strings to hold a binary tree with the root at [0], first row of children, left to right, at [1] and [2], etc.  While I haven't debugged that output format yet, I am much more concerned as to why that specific line is crashing my program.

I thought it was a pointer de-referencing issue, but `outStream << &contestList[i]` prints addresses as I'd expect, and `outStream << *contestList[i]` throws errors as I'd expect them to.

```
//3 lines are from other functions/files
typedef string elementType;
typedef elementType* elementTypePtr;
elementTypePtr contestList = new elementType[arraySize];

void BinTreeTourneyArray::printDownward(ostream &outStream)
{
    int row = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < getArraySize(); i++)
    {

        outStream << contestList[i]; //this is crashing the program

        if (isPowerOfTwo(i))
        {
            outStream << endl;
            row++;
        }
        else
        {
            outStream << ":";
        }
    }
}
```

arraySize is a private member `arraySize = ((2 * contestants) - 1)` where `contestants` is the number of contestants in my tournament.  Each round or "row" in the tree is synonymous with a tournament bracket.  If there are n contestants, then there are 2n-1 nodes needed in the tree.  The issue wouldn't be with this function.

```
getArraySize() { return arraySize; }
```

Comment: Show code for `arraySize` and `getArraySize`

Comment: _"A string pointer array"_ Shudder! Any concise reasons to use _arrays_ or _pointers_ with your code? Could you elaborate about these please?

Comment: it's added @pepperjack

Comment: What is the value of arraySize when you call new?  arraySize modified in any other place?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t use a raw pointer for your `contestList`. Instead, consider a `std::vector<elementType>`, or if the space overhead is a concern, `std::unique_ptr<elementType[]>`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `elementTypePtr contestList = new elementType[arraySize];` was the issue.  contestList was a private member of the class, then I threw this line in a function declaring a local variable of the same name that disappears after the function ends.  No biggie, except for the fact that I needed it in the print function...Oops.

Comment: And this illustrates two of the reasons why I suggested `unique_ptr` in the question comments above. 1. This means you were leaking wenever you called the function which created `contestList`; a `unique_ptr` would have avoided that. 2. More importantly, with `unique_ptr`, this would have left the class member at `nullptr`, which would have made this a lot easier to debug.